# Multiple thumbnails gallery when input changes

Tags: javascript, input, thumbnails

i have an input which type is file and when I change the values of this input, it shows thumbnails of images I choose (as a background).
My problem is that when I decide to change it second time, older images don't dissapear. My code below:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

   const inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("product-image");

   inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

   function previewImages() {

       let fileList = this.files;
       let anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

       for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {

           let objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
           const thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
           let image = document.createElement("div");
           thumbnail.append(image);
           let thumbnailDiv = document.querySelectorAll("#thumbnail div");
           thumbnailDiv[i].style.backgroundImage="url("+objectUrl+")";
           window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
       }

       let activeThumb= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#thumbnail div"));

       const handleClick = (e) => {

           activeThumb.forEach(node => {
               node.classList.remove("active");
           });

           e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
       }

       activeThumb.forEach(node => {
           node.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
   });

   }
});
```

```css
#thumbnail {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
#thumbnail div{
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 3px solid #E7E7E7 ;
 }
 #thumbnail div.active{
   border: 3px solid #9BC2EA ;
 }
```

```html
<input id="product-image" type="file" multiple>
<div id="thumbnail" class=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `const thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");` outside and above that loop. Then do `thumbnail.innerHTML = ''`, right after that, before your loop. You're only appending and never clearing out the Element contents.